# Can't narrow down deeply nested object prop

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get `message` from the first error in a type safe way:

```
// In a real case this is returned from the backend
const mutationError: unknown = {
    sources: {
        errors: [
            {
                message: 'Hello from error message'
            }
        ]
    }
};

const sources = (
    typeof mutationError === 'object'
    && mutationError
    && 'sources' in mutationError
    && typeof mutationError.sources === 'object'
    && mutationError.sources
);

// "sources" is typed as "false | object | null"

const errors = (
    typeof sources === 'object'
    && sources
    && 'errors' in sources
    && Array.isArray(sources.errors)
    && sources.errors
);

// "errors" is typed as "false | any[] | null"

const firstError = errors && errors[0];

// "firstError" is typed as "any"

const message = (
    typeof firstError === 'object'
    && firstError
    && 'message' in firstError
    && typeof firstError.message === 'string'
    && firstError.message
);
```

But for some reason `message` ends up as `any` and can't find way.

What I'm doing wrong?

Check this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgVygQygS3AUQE7ZNgLhgTAGswQB3MGAXhgG8AoGVmCEBbYAUwiOZshMHrnz8YAbRbDZg2QtZw+EZAHMeRAOQAJHgBt9IGADM8cEWOzwV6nlpmLWAX0fCAum9fOA3EyagkLAcXLwQdDAAFG5QAJ4ADjwgJvBIqBhgOHjWtLkwWiAARgBWPMBQDkIAZFWpKOhYVm41+SHcfFowaDSI9RlZ+M21cYnJdemN2QB0bWF0eQUlZRVD4w2ZVjOc7RBMAJR+AeDQltnh9NFCI0kps3zz9Iul5ZVsLXe71bVaomed3extmFVgBBXDIWJTNAQMHYCGRD5TX7iParRHI7C7A7+QInExoTFQAY5U7iGAtDEQSQABnch1xsGUEFUGgilzY1zG+MJxIe+SKzxWX1MBOgxNWWiZLPsXRo3LFTWFnJS8qJmyldj5Wmg2G6alerBaquJUw1Gn2PiAA).

Comment: I think the issue is that `Array.isArray()` narrows to `any[]` instead of `unknown[]`, as mentioned in [ms/TS#26188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26188).  You can work around it by wrapping it with your own version, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjprkm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, typing `firstError` as `unknown` seems to solve the issue. Thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It works on my IDE but for some reason it fails to compile using Webpack: `Property 'sources' does not exist on type 'object'`. Looks like it's ignoring the `in` operator?

Comment: It's a followup question, don't worry. I'll keep investigating and post a new question if I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) has [this call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/80ab111685e3e0c10d8d13cdd18d8dffa8328895/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1494):

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    isArray(arg: any): arg is any[];
}
```

which means that it narrows its argument to `any[]`, an array whose elements are of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  But `any` is "infectious" in that it absorbs all other types (`any & T` is just `any`) so it isn't helping you here. You get `any` everywhere thereafter.

Arguably it should *really* return `unknown[]` using [the safe `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) instead of `any[]`, but the call signature pre-dates the existence of `unknown`.  And while there is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#26188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26188) to change the TypeScript standard library to replace `any` with `unknown` (whose motivating example is somewhat coincidentally `Array.isArray()`), it would be a large breaking change to do so.  So it's probably never going to happen, unfortunately.

Until and unless that happens you should work around it.  One way to do it is to provide your own version of `Array.isArray()` that returns `unknown[]`. And the easiest approach to that is just wrap the function:

```
function isArray(x: any): x is unknown[] {
    return Array.isArray(x)
}
```

Now when you use that, you get `unknown` instead of `any`:

```
const errors = (
    typeof sources === 'object'
    && sources
    && 'errors' in sources
    && isArray(sources.errors)
    && sources.errors
);
// const errors: false | unknown[] | null

const firstError = errors && errors[0];
// const firstError: unknown
```

And that behaves better, since `unknown & T` is `T`:

```
const message = (
    typeof firstError === 'object'
    && firstError
    && 'message' in firstError
    && typeof firstError.message === 'string'
    && firstError.message
);
// const message: string | false | null
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgVygQygS3AUQE7ZNgLhgTAGswQB3MGAXhgG8AoGVmCEBbYAUwiOZshMHrnz8YAbRbDZg2QtZw+EZAHMeRAOQAJHgBt9IGADM8cEWOzwV6nlpmLWAX0fCAum9fOA3EyYmJMDo4DBoEACCuMgAngAUAB5EyGAxAJRECWEQxGQU1JLujG7YPFBcNFHYsQB04VWxiWlMrkygkLAcXLw59HFuUDEADjwgJvBIqBhgOHjWtAswWiAARgBWPMEOQgBkOxMoITNWbntLXdx8WmE0iIfTs-in+4MjYwdTWFY1Fz10i8t1psoNs2Gc7p9jnMfpxLhAmGk-G1wNBLHNejB+kJXqNxr8+P96ICNltnuxYT0yVpROjrmgaPj4bt9vVovFGTUaeJmszyd0+JyrPDEUwAPSimDtVFc7ASEzIfQQHgwAA+uXIVDAhVVMDACEM-ilsBMaFlUEe8zR4hgZxlEEkAAZ3H5xZKUcbTdALUQSBrqIb3TYIKoNHRMQNhrjTJ7zVZCUtViSQWSTWaLVTlMG7HSaKmvSdeTj3nnY9DMyHlQsidBsPS1KDWGcSxaauW7AiXRKjUGK0Qa3WdfLFcq1XqDUA)