# Why is TypeScript not detecting implicit use of any in nested object/array properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is Typescript not detecting that I've checked only part of unknown type, and not it's nested properties thus resulting in runtime error?

```
interface User {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const externalData: unknown = [1, 2, 3];

(Array.isArray(externalData) ? externalData : [])
    .reduce<User[]>((acc, curr) => {
        return [
            ...acc,
            {
                name: curr.some.nested.property, // not detecting that these properties may not exist on type 'any'
                age: curr.some.nested.another.propety // not detecting that these properties may not exist on type 'any'
            }
        ]
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like TypeScript is narrowing your `unknown` `externalData` to `any[]` when `Array.isArray(externalData)` is true. (I would have expected `unknown[]`.) [Here's a simpler case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgLhgVzAazCA7mGBeGAbQCIIQBbAUygAsBLMAc2IF0BuAKFElgEN8YAQQBOw3gE8AdHQgix4gBRwAlDAD88GEjDIANrs4B6QzFMwAemo5A):

```typescript
const d: unknown = ["something"];
const a = Array.isArray(d) ? d : null;
//    ^? const a: any[] | null
```

Notice how it's clearly the true part of the conditional that's contributing the `any[]` type to the union.

Just going by [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) (I don't have a deep history in this part of TypeScript, or really any part), that would seem to be a case that should be caught:

> In some cases where no type annotations are present, TypeScript will fall back to a type of `any` for a variable when it cannot infer the type...Turning on `noImplicitAny` however TypeScript will issue an error whenever it would have inferred `any`...

I don't see any issue for this in the [issue list](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues), although there are several outstanding issues with the result of narrowing array types (such as [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002) where `ReadonlyArray<T>` is narrowed to `any[]`).

I don't know whether it's me misinterpreting the documentation, a bug, or a limitation, but it's that narrowing that appears to be what isn't getting caught.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate but if I wrote an answer here it would look very much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77462373/2887218).  `Array.isArray()` uses `any[]` in its type predicate; `unknown` didn't exist when that was created, retroactively changing `any` to `unknown` in the TS library would break lots of people, so they haven't done it

Comment: @jcalz - I rather suspected it was because `unknown` didn't exist originally... :-) Thanks! (And OMG, that signature! I didn't realize it was so...simplistic. I really should have looked.)

Answer (score 0):

`noImplicit` will yell at you when there are no typings.
For example `function (foo) { ... }`,  `foo` has no type so it's implicitly `any`.

In your case `(Array.isArray(externalData) ? externalData : [])` is inferred to `any`.

because the empty array is `any[]`.

Comment: *"...because the empty array is `any[]`...."* That doesn't seem to be why, if I change the empty array top `[1]`, for instance, it still ends up inferring `any[]` for that expression (https://tsplay.dev/mbyR2N). Looks like the `any[]` comes from narrowing `unknown` to an array type, so it's the truthy branch in the conditional that contributes the `any[]` -- https://tsplay.dev/mpK7MN. I was looking for bugs in the issue list for this since it seems to fit the description of [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny): *"..whenever [TS] would have inferred `any`"*